# Responsive Design off canvas nav not appearing displaying between 600 and 830

Tags: css, responsive-design

On the site there is an off canvas nav built into the responsive design, but for some reason between the breakpoints of 600px and 830px the off canvas nav slides but it is completely white. It should display exactly the same as it does below 600px wide. Most likely it is something in the CSS. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS on line 1412 it changes .site overflow to hidden, which then hides the menu. It's under the media call for min-width: 600:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

...

.site {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    max-width: 73.14285714rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just remove overflow:hidden;

You may want to double check that nothing else breaks by changing this line, and maybe reapply it for the wider screens.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's always the little obvious things that we miss.